# Llevar variable a otra formulario

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Estoy intentando llevar variable cédula a otro formulario en TXbox  pero al ejecutar txbox queda en blanco

```
Cedula = Convert.ToString(reader["Cedula"]);
Intent intent = new Intent(this.Activity, typeof(PagPpal));
intent.PutExtra(PagPpal.MTxtCedula, Cedula);
```

**Formulario 1**

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Java.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Android.Content;

namespace LoginSystem
{
    public class OnLoginEventArgs
    {
        private string mTxtEmail;
        private string mTxtPassword;


        public string Email
        {
            get { return mTxtEmail; }
            set { mTxtEmail = value; }
        }
        public string Password
        {
            get { return mTxtPassword; }
            set { mTxtPassword = value; }
        }


        public void Dialog_Login() { }
        public void SDialog_Login(string email, string password)
        {
            this.Email = email;
            this.Password = password;

        }

        public OnLoginEventArgs(string email, string password)
        {
            this.Email = email;
            this.Password = password;
        }
    }

    public class Authenticate : DialogFragment
    {
        private EditText mTxtEmail;
        private EditText mTxtPassword;
        private Button mBtnAutenticate;
        internal int mOnLoginComplete;
        private string correo;

        public string Cedula { get; private set; }
        public string Nombre { get; private set; }
        public string Celular { get; private set; }
        public string Telefono { get; private set; }

        public event EventHandler<OnLoginEventArgs> MOnLoginComplete;
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Authenticate, container, false);
            mTxtEmail = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtEmail);
            mTxtPassword = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtPassword);
            mBtnAutenticate = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAutenticate);



            mBtnAutenticate.Click += (object sender, EventArgs args) =>
            {
                if (mTxtEmail.Text.Equals("") || mTxtPassword.Text.Equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Ha dejado campos vacios", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {

                        string strcon = "Server = sql10.freemysqlhosting.net; User = sql10179465; Password = afcm3008; Port = 3306";
                        string cadena = "select Cedula, Nombre, correo, Celular, Telefono from  sql10179465.Tbl_usuario where correo=@UserName and password =@Password";
                        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(strcon);
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cadena, con);

                        con.Open();

                        MySqlCommand com;

                        com = new MySqlCommand(cadena, con)
                        {
                            CommandType = CommandType.Text
                        };
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", mTxtEmail.Text);
                        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", mTxtPassword.Text);
                        MySqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();



                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                            FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                            PagPpal pagppalDialog = new PagPpal();
                            pagppalDialog.Show(transaction, "dialog fragment");
                            pagppalDialog.MOnPagPpalComplete += PagPpalDialog_mOnPagPpalComplete;

                            Cedula = Convert.ToString(reader["Cedula"]);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(this.Activity, typeof(PagPpal));
                            intent.PutExtra(PagPpal.MTxtCedula, Cedula);





                            Toast.MakeText(Activity, "", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.MakeText(Activity, "Error Datos ", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception m)

                    {

                    }
                }


            };
            return view;
        }

        private void PagPpalDialog_mOnPagPpalComplete(object sender, OnPagPpalEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

**Formulario 2**

```
textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCedula).Text = MTxtCedula;

using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace LoginSystem
{
    public class OnPagPpalEventArgs
    {
        public string mTxtCedula;
        public string mTxtFirstName;
        public string mTxtEmail;
        public string mTxtCelular;
        public string mTxtTelefono;

        public string Cedula

        {
            get { return mTxtCedula; }
            set { mTxtCedula = value; }
        }
        public string Nombre

        {
            get { return mTxtFirstName; }
            set { mTxtFirstName = value; }
        }

        public string Email

        {
            get { return mTxtEmail; }
            set { mTxtEmail = value; }
        }
        public string Celular

        {
            get { return mTxtCelular; }
            set { mTxtCelular = value; }
        }
        public string Telefono

        {
            get { return mTxtTelefono; }
            set { mTxtTelefono = value; }
        }


        public void Dialog_PagPpal() { }
        public void SDialog_PagPpal(string cedula, string nombre, string email, string telefono, string celular)

        {
            this.Cedula = celular;
            this.Nombre = nombre;
            this.Email = email;
            this.Celular = celular;
            this.Telefono = telefono;


        }
        public OnPagPpalEventArgs(string cedula, string nombre, string email, string telefono, string celular)
        {
            this.Cedula = celular;
            this.Nombre = nombre;
            this.Email = email;
            this.Celular = celular;
            this.Telefono = telefono;
        }
    }



    public class PagPpal : DialogFragment
    {
        public static readonly string MTxtCedula;
        public static readonly string MTxtFirstName;
        public static readonly string MTxtEmail;
        public static readonly string MTxtCelular;
        public static readonly string MTxtTelefono;


        internal int mOnPagPpalComplete;



        public event EventHandler<OnPagPpalEventArgs> MOnPagPpalComplete;
        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            var textView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.PagPpal, container, false);

            textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCedula).Text = MTxtCedula;

            textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtNombre).Text = MTxtFirstName;

            textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtEmail).Text = MTxtEmail;

            textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtCelular).Text = MTxtCelular;

            textView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtTelefono).Text = MTxtTelefono;


            return textView;
        }

        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            Dialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations = Resource.Style.dialog_animation;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Al ejecutar el textbbox se queda en blanco" ¿Que significa eso?

Comment: esto no parece ser ni javascript.. ese tag es incorrecto?

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Pues imagino que es Xamarin,pero no pondría la mano en el fuego..

Comment: gracias por su ayuda, la verdad soy nuevo en esto estoy realizando un login y lo que deseo es que si la persona que se loguea es exitosa al formulario siguiente le cargue sus datos completos.... en TextView .... y estoy en xamarin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el primer activity

```
button.Click += delegate {
       var Cedula = new Intent (this, typeof(Activity2));
       Cedula.PutExtra ("MyData", "Data from Activity1");
       StartActivity (activity2);
};
```

Y en el segundo activity recuperas el valor con la función GetStringExtra

```
 string ValorTextBoxRecuperado= Intent.GetStringExtra ("MyData") ?? "Data not available";
```